# Getting all event s g genreated by a recurrent event

Tags: calendar, recurring-events

I'm trying to get all the occurence generated by a recurrent event
with CSOM and CAML query

So for example if the event "Test" happens every year from today I would like to get the following dates occurences:

1/6/2017
1/6/2018
1/6/2019
....

My caml query is:

```
<Query>
<Where>
<And>
<Contains>
<FieldRef Name="Title" />
<Value Type='Text'>Test event</Value>
</Contains>
   <DateRangesOverlap>
    <FieldRef Name="EventDate" />
    <FieldRef Name="EndDate" />
    <FieldRef Name="RecurrenceID" />
    <Value Type='DateTime'><Year/></Value>
   </DateRangesOverlap>
</And>

  </Where>
<QueryOptions>
        <IncludeMandatoryColumns>false</IncludeMandatoryColumns>
        <ViewAttributes Scope="Recursive"/>
        <RecurrencePatternXMLVersion>v3</RecurrencePatternXMLVersion>
        <ExpandRecurrence>true</ExpandRecurrence>
        <RecurrenceOrderBy>true</RecurrenceOrderBy>
        <ViewAttributes Scope="RecursiveAll"/>
        <CalendarDate>
        <Today/>
        </CalendarDate>
    </QueryOptions>
</Query>
```

I see I can get  the RecurrenceData xml. Maybe I could infer the events from the xml retrieved but it is not easy to interpret.
Maybe there is a better way to gete the dates of each occurrence?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot retrieve it from SharePoint directly using CSOM. Instead you can use [SOAP request](https://codeplayandlearn.wordpress.com/2015/06/22/how-get-calendar-recurrent-events-by-csom-from-sharepoint-2013/).

To retrieve the same using CSOM, you can use the [SPCalendarRecurrenceExpander](https://github.com/ronnieholm/SPCalendarRecurrenceExpander/blob/master/README.md) package.